# «Некорректная» орфография в стихах/произведениях

Tags: орфография

Считается ли суперошибкой, если, например, вместо *постелют* в стихах написать *постелят*, чтоб именно такое было произношение этого слова? Стоит ли также писать специально, чтоб как бы «правильно» было, *расстояния* вместо *расстоянья*? Или писать *разносют* тоже нельзя вместо *разносят*, например в песне «Песенка о слухах» Высоцкого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Некорректная» орфография в стихах/произведениях — право автора!

В случае расстояния/расстоянья подмена меняет размер.

Comment: Размер чего? Это что?

Comment: Стихотворной строки, состоящей из определённого количества слогов.